# Reasons to use plain synchronous .getInfo() in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, async

When querying information from EE servers it is [advised](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.string.getinfo) to use asynchronous callbacks, e.g. `.evaluate()` or `.getInfo(callback)`. So the question is: are there **any** reasons to use plain synchronous `.getInfo()` at all, aside from its siplicity?

P.S. Of course there are cases where some parts of code must be executed after retrieving information from server, but even in those cases I see a better option in putting that code in a callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Python API, `.getInfo()` is necessary for printing and getting ee.Objects client-side because `.evaluate()` is not available [[doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install#printing-objects)].

Answer (score 0):

I have an example to demonstrate the necessity of getInfo(), in which evaluate or getInfo(callback) seems not available.

There is a while loop that will stop its iterations when the value of variable Flag is false.The value of Flag can only be extracted using getInfo() within the loop. I don't know if this code can be modified using evaluate or getInfo(callback).

```
  var Flag = true;

  while(Flag){           
    Flag = (some boolean operations).getInfo()==true;
}
```